# Format string to datetime using Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sql-date-functions

I am trying to convert and reformat a date column stored as a string using spark sql from something that looks like this...

```
30/03/20 02:00
```

to something that is a datetime column and looks like this...

```
2020-03-30 02:00 ('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

I am not using python but simply writing sql in DBeaver directly to a spark datalake. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [`to_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#to_timestamp) to parse string date into timestamp column and [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#date_format) to format it to desired pattern:

```
select date_format(to_timestamp(sting_date, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') as date
```

Comment: That worked thank you so much. Would you have a solution if I wanted to add the 4-digit year instead of just the 2-digit year? The original source only has '20' so I would imagine I would need to inset '20' in the string before the preceding 2-digit year to return a 4-digit year right?

Comment: yes that is correct. No sure if I need to somehow add '20' in the original string before converting through date_format. Otherwise, the solution is returning a 2-digit year.

Comment: You need just to change the date pattern. yy means 2-digit year and yyyy for 4-digit year. Please see [datetime patterns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) from the docs.